# Grafana/Prometheus Multi-value selection with avg() function

Tags: prometheus, grafana-variable

I'm trying to create a Grafana dashboard with **Multi-select** and **ALL** option to be enabled from variable.

Query exmple:
avg(metric{label1="$label1",label2=~"$label2",label3=~"$label3"})

Multi-select and ALL options looks fine in variable dropdown, but seems like prometheus query is doing the sum of label1 and label 2 and returning a single avg value, but I'm looking for multiple values based on the variable selection.

Example:
host1 - host4 10%
host2 - host5 15%
host3 - host6 20%

but instead of that it's returning value like below:
(host1,host2,host3) - (host4,host5,host6) - 20%

Any suggestion? or we can do it with avg() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by adding "by (label1,label2)" in the end

avg(metric{label1="$label1",label2=~"$label2",label3=~"$label3"}) by (label1,label2)